# 'a humbling experience' is what kind of experience?

Tags: word-usage

"golf is a humbling game"

Some dictionaries say : humbling=humiliating

I think humiliating is stronger than humbling in meaning.

I am familiar with the verb 'humble' but not with 'humbling'.

What's the nuance of 'humbling'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be humble is to be aware of your shortcomings or weaknesses. A humbling experience is one that makes you very aware of your weaknesses. Not necessarily humiliatingly so. Humiliation is pretty universally seen as negative, whereas humbling is not necessarily so, unless made negative by the context.

A humbling experience is just one that showed you that you are not all powerful, "knocked you down a peg" (this expression implies that you deserved it/ were too confident to begin with).

Comment: Excellent answer distinguishing ***humbling*** from ***humiliating***. Maybe not everyone would be as "linguistically tolerant" as me, but I have no problem at all with the idea that someone might be ***uplifted** by a **humbling** experience*. :)

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. The answer is wonderful. By the way, u are  not strict at language or grammar?